# Outlook Express - sending e-mail from the command line

Tags: email, command-line, outlook

What is the best way to send e-mail using outlook express from the command line? It has to be an automated operation with no user interaction. There will be some .jpg files in attachment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248569/starting-outlook-and-having-an-email-pre-populated-from-command-line) is helpful. It speaks pre-populating a new e-mail message and including a file.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really need to use Outlook Express to send the email?

Can't you use a third-party command line email tool or do you need it to use Outlook Express' settings and for the mails to end up in the Sent folder?

If you can use a third-party tool, something like [absoluteTools SendMail CMD](http://www.abspdf.com/products_toolsendmailcmd.html) might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This thread: [Send mail from a Windows script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152323/send-mail-from-a-windows-script#152411) might help you, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Quick'n dirty [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) script, you can modify it
to accept parameters from the command line:

```
; Send a mail vía outlook "automation"

$sRcpt = "test@test.com"
$sSubj = "Test subject"
$sBody = "This is a test"
$sAttach = "g:\AutoIt\AnHoras.PRG"

If Not WinActivate ("[REGEXPTITLE:.*\- Outlook Express]") Then
    RunWait ("d:\Archivos de programa\Outlook Express\msimn.exe")   ; Set your path to the Outlook .exe
Endif

Send ("!anm")   ; Archivo->Nuevo->Mensaje (in spanish, sorry, I suppose that in english it will be File->New->Message)
Send ($sRcpt & "{Tab 3}")
Send ($sSubj & "{Tab}")
Send ($sBody)

If $sAttach <> "" Then
    Send ("!i{Enter}" & $sAttach & "{Enter}")      ; Insertar adjunto (Insert->Attachment)
EndIf

Send ("!a{Down}{Enter}")        ; Archivo->Enviar mensaje (File->Send message)
```