# How can I send an email using a SMTP server using Windows Script?

Tags: smtp, wsh

I am new to Windows scripting. I saw the post on sending email on an Exchange server from WScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152323/send-mail-from-a-windows-script), but my scenario is a little different.

We need to be able to send the mail using any SMTP server configured in any of our networks from the Windows Script. Can you please help?

- IM_IBM

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided in the question you [refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152323/send-mail-from-a-windows-script) will actually work with any SMTP server. Take a look at the following links which explain how to use CDOSYS:

[ASP Sending e-mail with CDOSYS (W3Schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp)

[Sending SMTP Mail by Port 25 Using CDOSYS (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms992546(EXCHG.65).aspx)

Kev